# Enable Chrome omnibox suggestions without instant search

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I can't figure out how to enable Chromium/Chrome omnibox suggestions, while keeping instant search off. Just the way it can be done in Google Web Search web interface. Am I missing something?

Comment: Omnibox suggestions use Instant Search on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice before, but omnibox *does* show suggestions without Instant—but not as many as Google Web Search web interface, and the suggestion algorithm seems inconsistent—sometimes results are shown and sometimes not.

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694725/increasing-the-number-of-suggests-shown-in-omnibox) on Stack Overflow—it seems not possible currently to increase omnibox results.